# Problem with external playback on Canon SX50 HS Powershot

Tags: video, video-quality, video-recording

I have a Canon SX50 HS Powershot and recently I discovered that when I play videos on my SD card on my computer using the Windows Media Player, the video quality itself is much more pixelated and tinted in darker colors. I have other videos which are much higher quality when I play them on my computer so this has raised me to ask you the question of whether or not the problem is to do with the computer itself, my camera which plays videos very high quality on its LCD screen or the SD card I use (Sandisk microSD 8Gb).

Comment: Many things could be a factor, wrong codec / no codec installed on your PC to which WMP is trying to use something else to decode the video, the spec of the PC is not enough to play the file. have you tried copying it to the HDD of the PC and playing it from there ? does it play OK in another PC or Mac ?

Comment: 1. copy videos from card to hdd, maybe slow read cause it. 2. you cant judge by LCD screen as it is only 1megapixel. 3. try another player as VLC for example